# How to change the CKeditor button for media library module

Tags: media, 9, wysiwyg

The Drupal 9 Media Library includes a button for CKeditor. The button depicts an image icon combined with musical notes. We plan to only use this button for video. How can I replace this button with one of our own design?

Comment: You can try to [change the default CKEditor skin](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/ckeditor-api/overview) to yours implementing [`hook_editor_js_settings_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21editor%21editor.api.php/function/hook_editor_js_settings_alter/8.2.x). If you don't want to make a completely new skin, just copy the default one with changes you want to implement. The default skin can be found on core/assets/vendor/ckeditor/skins/moono-lisa.